# How to get the name of the form - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine and Twig. I have two forms created in this way:

```
class PaymentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'required'  => false));
        // ...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'payments';
    } 
}
```

The second is similar but getName() returns 'edit'

Each of the has its own submit button. How can I get the name of the form whose submit button was pressed? The thing I want to do is to find a way the controller to identify which button was pressed because each of them should make different things happen.

Comment: Why not simply use two separate controllers to process the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
public function processAction(Request $request)
{
    $form_a = $this->createForm(new FormAType());
    $form_b = $this->createForm(new FormBType());

    if ($request->request->has($form_a->getName())) {
        // form a was sent
    } else if ($request->request->has($form_b->getName())) {
        // form b was sent
    }

    // any additional code
}
```